# Is there a way to stop a url redirecting using javascript or Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

for example when you click on this flickr url: http://www.flickr.com/photos/caterpiya/5716797477/sizes/h/

The /sizes/h/ changes to /sizes/l/ how can I stop it from making this change and be given an alert through Jquery or javascript if it goes to a 404?

```
<script>
    function yo(){
        var href = "http://www.flickr.com/photos/caterpiya/5716797477/"
        href = href+"sizes/h/";
        window.open(href);
    }
</script>
<button  onclick="yo()">open</button>
```

Comment: set a class for those buttons, otherwise you cant identify it directly.

Comment: You shouldn't have quotes around `href` in `window.open()`.

Comment: I don't think you can find out about this redirection. Since the window is in a different domain from you, you can't inspect it.

Comment: If you are just redirecting, you will never know if the URL is being redirected. An option is to fetch the page via AJAX and read the response headers, I think that should tell you the final URL.

Comment: @DavidNguyen How would I go about doing that?

Comment: @user2768038 I took a look don't think you can do this with just javascript because of security issues, you will need something server side to do a curl request and return the url

Comment: On another note, unless you are certain the audience is guaranteed to support JavaScript or if you don't care about those who don't, this breaks usability with those who have JavaScript turned off, or are using browsers that don't have it built in (such as lightweight text-based browsers).

Comment: @DavidNguyen: 302 redirects will be transparent to the XHR. (You don't get to intervene).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about using a global variable? Something like:

```
<script>
    var isUrlClicked = false;

    function yo(){
        var href = "http://www.flickr.com/photos/caterpiya/5716797477/"
        href = href+"sizes/h/";
        isUrlClicked = true;
        window.open("href");
    }
</script>

<button  onclick="yo()">open</button>
```